# Missing Icons in default Icons-Object in Android Studio / Flutter project: The getter 'menu_book' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, icons, flutter-dependencies

I'm pretty new to flutter please excuse if I'm missing an obvious point here.

I am sharing a flutter project on github with one of my friends. I'm using some Icons directly form the "Icons" Object like this:

```
Icon(
  Icons.menu_book,
  size: 60,
  color: kColCardIcon,
);
```

He now gets the following error message when trying to compile the project:

```
error: The getter 'menu_book' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'. (undefined_getter at [awesomeapp] lib\ui\screens\home_screen.dart:115)
```

Flutter doctor reports no errors on both installations.
flutter clean won't help.
Aren't these icons part of the material or cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0 ? (Both have the same version in the pubspec file)

Does anyone have an idea why this icons could be missing, or where we could check for a missing setting/include?